# Why I got the error: The tag helper 'body' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area

Tags: asp.net-core, compiler-errors, razor-pages

I've changed my pure usual body element in my _Layout.cshtml file from

```
<body data-my-attibute='myattributevalue'>
```

to

```
<body  @myAttributes>
```

and getting an error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   RZ1031  The tag helper 'body' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area.

The body element does not look and behave like a tag helper
To be short: H E L P, this is a knife in my back Friday afternoon...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well this is a shame but I am leaving here, there is a slight chance it helps someone...

```
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.TagHelpers.BodyTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
```

Comment: In case someone needs to know where to put this line of code, it typically goes in the _ViewImports.cshtml file in your shared folder.

Answer (score 17):

I had similar problem, i learned from documentation that you can disable a Tag Helper on a single tag by prepending !,  so your code would be:

```
<!body  @myAttributes>
</!body>
```

Comment: Here's the [link to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#opting-out-of-individual-elements).